# access denied ;you need super privilege for this operation in sql query browser

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am very new to sql. Now i am trying  to host an application in amazon which uses a database. so i create an ec2 instance and use sql query browser connecting to rds instance in amazon.I import the .sql dump file and executed that. i am getting error in this statement...
CREATE DEFINER='root'@localhost 'PROCEDURE'delete_user_message'(in id varchar(20))
as Access denied ;you need (atleast one of) the super privileges for this operation .error (1227).How can i fix this and create the database

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that in RDS you don't get SUPER privileges, which is required to create a procedure owned by another user. To make this work, all you need to do is remove the `DEFINER` portion of your statement. Then it will automatically use the current user.

Comment: Removing DEFINER section does work. However, the DEFINER section is commented out anyway. Why would remove comment make it work? My DEFINER portion is as "< /*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`ibaobaotest`@`localhost`*/  "

Comment: @MichaelZ I believe its only commented out for version of mysql that don't support it. 50017 indicates version 5.0.17 or higher.