# PHPMYADMIN sql file is not importing

Tags: sql, database, import, hosting, cpanel

I have changed my hosting Company from one to another. I tried importing my SQL file and I get this error.

Error
SQL query:

/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED /
/!50013 DEFINER=onlinea2@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER /
/!50001 VIEW vwallorders AS select tbl_gf_codes.CodeId AS Id,cast(tbl_gf_codes.RequestedAt as date) AS OrderDate,tbl_gf_codes.UserId AS UserId from tbl_gf_codes union select tbl_gf_codes_slbf.CodeId AS Id,cast(tbl_gf_codes_slbf.RequestedAt as date) AS OrderDate,tbl_gf_codes_slbf.UserId AS UserId from tbl_gf_codes_slbf union select tbl_gf_log_requests.LogRequestId AS Id,cast(tbl_gf_log_requests.RequestedAt as date) AS OrderDate,tbl_gf_log_requests.UserId AS UserId from tbl_gf_log_requests */

#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Give permission to the user ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [access denied ;you need super privilege for this operation in sql query browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559099/access-denied-you-need-super-privilege-for-this-operation-in-sql-query-browser)